Struggling with finding exit angle from pole in Root Locus
I'm trying to draw the root locus for $$G(s) = \frac{1}{(s^2+4s+4)(s^2+8s+16)} = \frac{1}{(s+2)^2(s+4)^2}$$
for $K >0$. Computing asymptotes yielded $\pm \frac{\pi}{4}, \pm \frac{3\pi}{4}$ which is fine - but I'm struggling with computing the exit angle from either pole. I'm using this formula that our TAs use:
$$-\Phi + \angle [G(s_0]^\# = \pi$$
where $\Phi$ is the exit angle and $\angle [G(s_0)]^\#$ is the phase of the plant at pole $s_0$ without the pole. I keep getting phase 0, which nets me $\Phi = -\pi$ which doesn't make much sense when you compare it to the root locus plot by wolfram alpha. Where am I wrong?

Consider the three sections on the real axis and a test point on them.

right of $-2+0i$. All the poles contribute 0 degrees to the test point and hence the angle criterion of $\pi$ is not satisfied. So the root locus does not pass through any point on the real axis to the right of $-2+0i$.

left of $-4+0i$. All the 4 poles contribute 180 degrees to the test point and hence the angle criterion of odd multiple of $\pi$ is not satisfied. So the root locus does not pass through any point on the real axis to the left of $-4+0i$.

between $-4+0i$ and $-2+0i$. The two poles at $-2+0i$ contribute 180 deg each. The two poles at $-4+0i$ contribute zero. Hence totally, even multiple of $\pi$. So criterion not satisfied. So root locus does not lie on this part of the real axis either.


(In fact, some text books will say that odd/evenness of the number of poles and zeros to the right of the test point on the real axis is a check for whether sections of real axis are part of root locus or not.)
Now consider a test point just above the double pole $-2+0i$ (e.g. $-2+0.000000001i$). Each pole at $-2+0i$ contributes $\pi/2$. The two poles at $-4+0i$ contribute nearly zero. Hence angle criterion is satisfied. So the root locus passes through a point directly above $-2+0i$. i.e., angle of departure is 90 deg. since there are two poles, -90 deg angle of departure also can be found to be valid.
Same argument on a point just above the $-4+0i$ point will show that angle of departure is 90 deg and -90 deg there also.
The reason your computation didn't give the correct answer may be because the points your are testing have double poles on them. The formula used might be valid only for single poles. In such doubtful cases, use first principle arguments.
